# the UIView's reference said " bounds (Not available in swift)", what does that mean?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

The reference said:

> bounds (Not available in Swift)
>
> center (Not available in Swift)
>
> transform (Not available in Swift)

But in swift project I still can use those three property on UIView instances, so What does "Not available in Swift" means???

Here is what show in Dash:
[image: doc version]
[image: doc problem]

Comment: Which reference said this? Can you provide a link?

Comment: in this (url)[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform] I can't find it, but in Dash I found it!

Comment: @vacawama I have update the question description

Comment: This appears to be a dash issue, unrelated to `iOS`, `Swift`, and `UIView`'s.  I suggest you update or delete and reinstall that documentation.  If that doesn't update, notify dash or whoever builds the documentation, then just use apple's in the meantime.

Comment: This is not an issue with Dash. The official Apple documentation shows these properties as unavailable in Swift. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW51